# Lollipop EditBox styling

Tags: android, android-edittext, themes, android-5.0-lollipop

I currently have this one:
[image: sreenshot]

Is it possible to remove black stroke and have only highlighted? Does it violate any Google guideline about material design

Comment: I just discover joy for my weekends learning https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/res/res/values/styles.xml. So it is possible but will require own drawable creation. I will post answer if noone will answer faster

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is totally an android lollipop bug. It happens to the framework and AppCompat version of the EditText and will be fixed in a future release. See here: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=80180

Comment: Thanks, so I could just wait for newer release

Comment: Afaik this bug has been fixed in 5.1

Comment: Confirm that it is fixed!