# EditText android L stylin'

Tags: java, android, mobile, android-edittext, android-5.0-lollipop

I'm having troubles styling my EditText on Android L.

It looks like the EditText widget now takes your colorAccent color specified in your app wide theme and uses that as the underline color for the widget. That'd be great, but it also seems to darken it and add a second line above the colorAccent colored line. An example from the Reddit Is Fun app:

[image]

You can see that the lighter blue underline color is the apps accent color. The system then darkens it and adds another line. It looks alright here, but in my app it goes from a bright green to a dark green color and looks awful. Is there any easy way to specify that should just be accentColor?

I've tried setting the tint property on the EditText. That colors it correctly, but it then loses the color change when focused vs unfocused. It also gets applied app-wide...which feels weird.

Thanks guys.

Comment: The double-underline is a framework bug. How are you applying a tint to the EditText?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As alanv said, it is actually a bug. See the following SO question:

[Lollipop EditBox styling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27123278/lollipop-editbox-styling/27132324#27132324)

Answer (score 0):

Check the last reply of this question: [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26574328/changing-edittext-bottom-line-color-with-appcompat-v7)

Take care, the drawable is in /app/package/build...